# Tap to click on OS X login screen?

Tags: macos, osx-snow-leopard, login-screen

I'm using OS X Snow Leopard, on a Macbook Pro.

Is there any way to "tap to click" (on the trackpad) instead of pressing down on the trackpad when interacting with the login screen?

It's not really that big of a deal, but I'm curious.

Comment: Do you want to improve on the speed you login? The fastest is to type in your username, press `tab`, type in your password, hit `enter`. Pretty fast, no need to even touch the mouse ;)

Comment: True. It's just a matter of personal preference for me though. :)
 Right now I type the first letter of my user name, press enter, type my password in, press enter, voila! But I'm not used to doing that when logging into other accounts (like a standard account which I often use for testing things), and other users aren't accustomed to "press to click" on a trackpad as much either, which is why I asked this question :)

Comment: See also [How can I enable Trackpad tap-to-click for the login window in OS X 10.8? - Ask Different](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/58461/how-can-i-enable-trackpad-tap-to-click-for-the-login-window-in-os-x-10-8).

Answer (score 7):

[This Mac OS X Hints article](http://www.macosxhints.com/article.php?story=20070224105049800) explains how to do this.

Quote:

> After some digging, I found it in a
>   hidden preferences file called
>   .GlobalPreferences.plist in my user's
>   Library/Preferences folder. I found
>   the same file in the top-level
>   /Library/Preferences folder, and then
>   added the com.apple.mouse.tapBehavior
>   setting as a class of Number with a
>   value of 1 and saved the file.

**EDIT:** Or, a user suggestion:

`defaults write /Library/Preferences/.GlobalPreferences com.apple.mouse.tapBehavior -int 1`

**EDIT2:** Since I don't have a Mac with a trackpad and OS 10.5 or later (The only Mac with a trackpad I have access to is a Powerbook running 10.4), please let me know what the output of

`ls ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.driver*`

is. Hopefully you'll have a file like `/Users/jnet/Library/Preferences/com.apple.driver.AppleHIDMouse.plist` which you can copy to /Library/Preferences to make this behavior work.

**EDIT3:** I'm playing with a MacBook Pro at an apple store right now. I think the file is `~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.systempreferences.plist` -- Try copying *that* file to `/Library/Preferences/`...

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for me. I manually opened it with a plist editor and changed it and eventually saved it... didn't work. Then I ran the terminal command... didn't work. I've rebooted too... 
Does it work for you? Or is it just my computer on which this trick doesn't work?
Thanks for answering though :)

Comment: I read the article and it doesn't seem to work for OS X Leopard. Is this possibly also true with Snow Leopard, which is what I use?

Comment: I don't have a Snow Leopard macBook to test this on... I'm on an iMac. I'm googling a bit more to find a solution for you.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Just wondering: it does work for you right? What  version of OS X do you use if any?

Comment: I user 10.5.8. But that's on an iMac with no touch pad. The only Mac with a touchpad I have access to is a Powerbook running 10.4... Try my edited solution, let me know if you have any plist files which might help

Comment: Alright. Let me test it. :) I've voted you up anyways for your help.

Comment: You know, after searching for some while, I'm thinking that this is simply impossible. Perhaps the trackpad driver doesn't even completely load at the login screen or something... :)

Comment: In response to EDIT2: There's one file in my ~/Library/Preferences folder: com.apple.driver.AppleIRController.plist. I think that has to do with an apple remote though, or something like that, not at all with the trackpad.

Comment: @Nano8Blazex: yes. I have the same on my iMac and it does have to do with the remote. We'll see if anyone else has a bright idea... if I can think of anything else I'll post another edit

Comment: I'll accept this answer since... well... it's the best anyone could come up with. :)

Comment: @Nano8Blazex: If you leave it open and don't accept my answer, then someone else might answer later. Also, you will be able to offer a bounty on the question. When I have more time I'll play around a bit more and see if I can find a real solution.

Comment: @Josh: Well, if you say so. :)

Comment: OK. Now I think I have it, see EDIT3

Comment: It doesn't seem to work. Well, probably I have to reboot first, let me try that.

Comment: After reboot: still no success. :O

Comment: Damn, I thought I had it! Obviously I can't get admin access to the machines in the apple store to confirm this would work, but I was hopeful...

Comment: Well, it was a good idea :)

Answer (score 1):

yes, Open  - settings, - trackpad - there should be an option listed that allows taps for clicks.

Comment: I've already tried that, but it doesn't affect the login screen, only my own user account. Thanks for answering though!

Comment: Just a thought, will doing that as a root user work? Let me test it out...

Comment: No, unfortunately it doesn't. I have heard that changing the login screensaver works via root though.

Comment: Oh man...sorry -I miss the "login screen part" - I do not know of a way to change that. sorry